# DirectX wont run games

Tags: gaming, directx

My DxDiag says that I have DirectX 12 but games like battleborn always say I need 11 to be able to play. I'm new to this and have no Idea what to do.`

`

> ---
>
> ### System Information

```
  Time of this report: 12/5/2016, 22:03:11
         Machine name: FREY
           Machine Id: {C64C9B92-14C8-4020-AA55-72B8566A0EFF}
     Operating System: Windows 10 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 14393) (14393.rs1_release_inmarket.161102-0100)
             Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
  System Manufacturer: ASUSTek Computer Inc.
         System Model: G60JX
                 BIOS: BIOS Date: 06/15/09 18:50:05 Ver: 08.00.10
            Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 430  @ 2.27GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.3GHz
               Memory: 4096MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 3958MB RAM
            Page File: 4659MB used, 1730MB available
          Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
  DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
   System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
      DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
             Miracast: Not Available
```

Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.14393.0000 64bit Unicode

---

### DirectX Debug Levels

Direct3D:    0/4 (retail)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (retail)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (retail)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)

---

### Display Devices

```
      Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTS 360M
   Manufacturer: NVIDIA
      Chip type: GeForce GTS 360M
       DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
    Device Type: Full Device
     Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0CB1&SUBSYS_203C1043&REV_A2
  Device Status: 0180200A [DN_DRIVER_LOADED|DN_STARTED|DN_DISABLEABLE|DN_NT_ENUMERATOR|DN_NT_DRIVER]
```

Device Problem Code: No Problem
Driver Problem Code: Unknown
     Display Memory: 2950 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 972 MB
      Shared Memory: 1978 MB
       Current Mode: 1366 x 768 (32 bit) (60Hz)
       Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
      Monitor Model: HSD160PHW1
         Monitor Id: HSD0640
        Native Mode: 1366 x 768(p) (59.999Hz)
        Output Type: Internal
        Driver Name: nvd3dumx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll
Driver File Version: 21.21.0013.4200 (English)
     Driver Version: 21.21.13.4200
        DDI Version: 11.1
     Feature Levels: 10_1,10_0,9_3,9_2,9_1
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.2
Graphics Preemption: DMA
 Compute Preemption: DMA
           Miracast: Not Supported by Graphics driver
Hybrid Graphics GPU: Not Applicable
     Power P-states: Not Applicable
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 10/17/2016 4:00:00 PM, 17559200 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: Yes
    WHQL Date Stamp: Unknown
  Device Identifier: {D7B71E3E-4FF1-11CF-9B63-310018C2D835}
          Vendor ID: 0x10DE
          Device ID: 0x0CB1
          SubSys ID: 0x203C1043
        Revision ID: 0x00A2

Comment: Are those games properly installed or just leftovers from a previous Windows installations?

Comment: The games? They should be properly installed since its on steam sorry as I said I'm new to it.

Answer (score 0):

could it be related to the directX version having the 3D component...? perhaps that game needs stuff from 11 that 12 doesn't have / have changed slightly?

i have been seeing a pattern with windows 10 not liking directX for some reason..?

test another game of similar GPU requirements with your existing DirectX12...? run a report and compare the two attempts....? one thing i do know for sure is system resore that b%^^ before touching anything - found this out the hard way too many times ;)

Zen

Comment: You did not provide a solution to OP